# Correctly defining an array in set theory

Tags: notation

I wonder as a hobby mathematician if I could define a non-typed array (in the context of computer science) with set theory.

My best guess to this would be a finite multiset of cardinality 1

```
array = {(i, Si) | i ∈ ℕ0 ^ #S = 1}
```

I wonder if I am missing some details due to my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You could define an array of size $n$ to just be any function with domain $\{1,...,n\}$.

Comment: ... or (in the context of computer science) with domain$\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$

Comment: would that be able to define any array. The original reason I'd added the set S was to imply that an array was a set of order homogenous sets.

Comment: @Saxpy Not sure what "set of order homogeneous sets" means.

Comment: @KeeferRowan sorry, I am not very good with words. I mean to say something like, suppose I have set INT which represents all integer numbers representable by a computer. If I wanted to represent an array of size 3, I could have { {0, INT}, {1, INT}, {2, INT} }. Here, I am trying to represent a set of 3 sets which contain an index and the INT set (same for all 3).